# Re-arrange files starting from desired file with awk one-liner

Tags: sorting, awk

Let's assume we have these regular sorted files in a unix/linux folder.

```
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
D.txt
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

`command D.txt` must sort as:

```
D.txt -> begin with selected file
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
A.txt -> append remaining files in order
B.txt
C.txt
```

`command b.txt` must sort as:

```
b.txt
c.txt
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
D.txt
a.txt
```

I tried such scripts below but awk seems doesn't re-arrange output in a way that I desired. Command always sorts regular order.

```
#!/bin/sh
export fname="$1"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | awk -v ref="./$fname" '($0 > ref) {print $0} ($0 < ref) {print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffer lines until `ref`, print `ref` and succesive lines as they arrive, and print buffer at the end.

```
awk -v ref="./$fname" '$0==ref{f=1} f{print;next} {buf=buf $0 ORS} END{printf "%s",buf}'
```

Demo:

```
$ seq 5 | awk -v ref=3 '$0==ref{f=1} f{print;next} {buf=buf $0 ORS} END{printf "%s",buf}'
3
4
5
1
2
```